# Deleting files using Swift that require admin privileges

Tags: swift, admin, delete-file, nsfilemanager, smjobbless

I am currently working on a Mac Application where I need to delete files(potentially malicious) from /Library/LaunchDaemons directory and other similar directories where I would need administrator privileges. Using the `FileManager.default.removeItem` was not fruitful. I have come across articles pointing me towards `EvenBetterAuthorizationSample` and `SMJobBless` and I find the documentation to be rather confusing. Am I on the right track and if so, how should I proceed?

Comment: Look at [SwiftPrivilegedHelper](https://github.com/erikberglund/SwiftPrivilegedHelper)

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to look at the `init(authorization:)` method of the FileManager. It is available since 10.14. I think it is the easiest way to perform the operation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/3025773-init

Also, it worth checking if the directories you want to delete are not protected by SIP. In this case on SIP-enabled machines there is no way to remove them.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer Julia. This way certainly seems to be the easiest. But, I am unable to figure out the right way to use it. Can you give me an example, say to perform a privileged removeItem() operation using FileManager?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `SMJobBless` is indeed confusing. I've put together the [SwiftAuthorizationSample](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SwiftAuthorizationSample) along with a pretty extensive README. So even if the sample isn't quite what you're looking for, hopefully the README will be of some help.